# equation of a perpendicular bisector

Tags: analytic-geometry

A diagram shown has point A( -2 , 4 ) , B ( 6, 2 ), C (-4,-4) find the equation of the line perpendicular to BC and passing through the midpoint of BC (M). Give answers in general form.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Please don't dump undigested, unsourced problems here with no sign of any effort on your part. Please tell us where the problem comes from, why it interests you, what you know about it, what progress you can make on it, where you get stuck, and so on.

Comment: Author unresponsive to comments. Question appears to be abandoned. Voting to close. 

Answer (score 2):

To find the equation of the line perpendicular to the line $BC$ formed by the points $B = ( 6, 2 ), \;C = (-4,-4)$, we need to

- first, find the slope of line $BC$: $$\text{slope of BC}:\;\; m = \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$
- Then, the slope of the line perpendicular to $BC$ is given by $m_\perp = \left( -\dfrac 1m\right)$.
- Next, you need to determine the *midpoint* $(x_0, y_0)$ of line $BC$ using the given points: $B = ( 6, 2 ), \;C = (-4,-4)$.
- Now you'll have the slope $m_\perp$ and the point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the perpendicular line from which you can create the equation of the desired line: $$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$

Comment: I like answers like this, nicely steps them through, but they have to do work. +1

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks. Yes, with questions like this, I prefer to outline the process. When I get feedback from the OP, if I get feedback showing effort, I'm willing to elaborate, clarify, confirm.