# Given 2 points and a line which contains the center point

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the general equation of the circle containing $(-4,-2)$ and $(2,0)$, and whose center is contained on the line $5x-2y=19$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The center of the circle is the common point of the perpendicular bisector line of the segment that has  as extremes the two given points,  $A=(-4,-2)$ and $B=(2,0)$, and the given straight line : $5x-2y=19$.

Comment: How should I start solving this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to find the perpendicular bisector of a segment? If not you can see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545293/equation-of-a-perpendicular-bisector

Comment: (y-y)=m(x-x) is that it? Uhm point-slope intercept form, is the name correct, I can only barely remember it